# What does mutex locks lock exactly in golang?

Tags: go, locking, mutex

In below code how do I distinguish between gloabllock and entrylock and what it is locking exactly

```
type cacheImpl struct {
    globalLock       sync.Mutex
    EntryLock map[string]*sync.Mutex
        
    abc map[string]int
}
```

I expect the entrylock to lock only one int entry corresponding to the key. But how is this reference created.

Answer (score 4):

I would say your way of thinking about this is flawed: a mutex does not lock anything other than *itself.* By extention, when we say a particular mutex protects some particular variable (or a set of variables), we imply this happens by virtue of *all possible code paths* which access that variable (or that set) coherently using that very mutex.

In other words, a mutex by itself is just a synchronization primitive which implements specific rule about calling its `Lock` method: as long as the mutex is locked, any call to its `Lock` method suspends the calling goroutine until a mutex is unlocked, after which each currently suspended calling goroutine wakes up and "retries" to lock the mutex with only one of them succeeding at that.

Hence, to make a mutex useful, you have to couple it with specific workflow you yourself implement.

I do not quite parse your question but if you intend to make mutexes in `EntryLock` manage access to same-key entries in `abc`, then you roll like this:

- When adding a new entry:

  1. Lock `globalLock`;
  2. Add an entry to `abc`;
  3. Add an entry to `EntryLock` – this may look just like `EntryLock[theKey] = new(sync.Mutex)`;
  4. Unlock `globalLock`.
- When using an entry:

  1. Lock `globalLock`;
  2. Lock `EntryLock[theKey`];
  3. Mess with `abc[theKey]`;
  4. Unlock `EntryLock[theKey]`;
  5. Unlock `globalLock`.
- Deleting an entry is deleting items from two maps while holding `globalLock`.

Note that you *have to* hold the `globalLock` even if you want to lock a single `abc` entry.
If you're OK with some goroutine concurrently removing a "locked entry" from the map, you can do

1. Lock `globalLock`;
2. Lock `EntryLock[theKey`];
3. Unlock `globalLock`.
   Note that now any other goroutine might remove `abc[theKey]` and `EntryLock[theKey]` while you're working with them;
4. Mess with `abc[theKey]`;
5. Unlock `EntryLock[theKey]`;

…and then note that if you're not OK with some goroutine removing the currently locked entry from the maps, you must hold the global lock for the whole duration of processing a single entry, and in this case you do not need per-entry locks at all.

As a last note, you might look at [`sync.Map`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Map) which is a map with serialized insertions/reads/deletions. Be sure to carefully read the docs first.

Answer (score 1):

> I expect the entrylock to lock only one int entry corresponding to the key. But how is this reference created.

It's not.

While a few languages have such a link explicitly by the mutex being a container, in its theoretical conception and in most implementations a mutex is not formally linked to any datum<sup>1</sup>. Any relation between locks and data has to be handled by the developer.

Note that even in languages with data-bearing locks, locks are tricky things to manage e.g. it's easy to deadlock when taking locks in different orders.

---

1: not only that, but lots of mutexes lock *code* (so-called critical sections), and may not have any specific datum they can be associated with